# adding PictureBox array into Controls

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, picturebox

I tried adding PictureBox array into controls but only one pictureBox is being added.

```
Label[] l = new Label[15];
PictureBox[] pic1 = new PictureBox[15];
int y_value = 47;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{

    l[i] = new Label();
    l[i].Text = "Test Text";
    l[i].Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(128)));
    l[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    l[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(1, 0, 64);
    l[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(145, 20);
    l[i].Location = new Point(30, y_value);
    l[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
    l[i].Visible = true;
    //this.Controls.Add(l[i]);

    pic1[i] = new PictureBox();
    pic1[i].Image = Image.FromFile(STR_SETTING_PATH + "\\" + STR_IDEA_NO_XXXXX + "_01_nv.png");
    pic1[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 332);
    pic1[i].Location = new Point(2, y_value - 10);
    pic1[i].Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
    pic1[i].Visible = true;
    //this.Controls.Add(pic1[i]);

    y_value += 37;
}

this.Controls.AddRange(l);
this.Controls.AddRange(pic1);
```

When I do this, the labels are displaying correctly, but only one PictureBox is appearing. I tried changing X,Y positions, but it did not help. The debugger shows lists of array of PictureBox initialized. Is there anything that I am doing wrong or what is the better approach to add PictureBox with Label above it dynamically.

Comment: you increase y_value by 37. the height of your pictureBox is 332. so they might overlap.

Comment: Yep... Was my mistake... Silly me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code and in fact they do overlap. (increased red in backgroundcolor by y_value / 2 every iteration).

[image]

set height of your PictureBox to (f.e.) 20 and you will see that they show up just fine:

```
Label[] l = new Label[15];
PictureBox[] pic1 = new PictureBox[15];
int y_value = 47;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{

    l[i] = new Label
    {
        Text = "Test Text",
        Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 8, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte) (128))),
        ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White,
        BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(1, 0, 64),
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(145, 20),
        Location = new Point(30, y_value),
        Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left,
        Visible = true
    };

    pic1[i] = new PictureBox
    {
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 20),
        Location = new Point(2, y_value - 10),
        Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left,
        Visible = true,
        BackColor = Color.FromArgb(y_value/2, 0, 0)
    };

    y_value += 37;
}

this.Controls.AddRange(l);
this.Controls.AddRange(pic1);
```

[image]